# ggplot radiotracking periods

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my first question here at StackOverflow, so please tell me if I have made some mistakes in the posting process and I will edit the question asap.

I'm a ggplot2 newbie and I would like to plot radiotracking periods using this package. My data consists of coordinate locations of animals taken in uneven intervals (VHF-type data) during the active season (from 15/05 until 15/09) of 2 different years (2011-2012).

What I would like to do is to show how much every individual has been radiotracked throughout the active season of its year in the best way possible.

I know that it sounds complicated, therefore I have made an example of what I mean and what I was able to achieve up to now.
The column "Dropped" means that the transmitter dropped from the animal and was subsequently reattached, this also means that in that time span without transmitter, the animal could not be radiotracked.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
 ##transform the data for ggplot
traj$Date<-as.Date(as.character(traj$Date),"%Y%m%d")
traj$Date<-as.POSIXct(traj$Date)
traj$Year<-as.factor(traj$Year)
##plot graph
inf<-as.POSIXct(as.Date('20110515',format="%Y%m%d"))
sup<-as.POSIXct(as.Date('20110915',format="%Y%m%d"))
direplot <- ggplot(traj, aes(x=Date, y=Name,colour=Year,drop=TRUE)) + 
  geom_point()+
labs(title="Radiotracking scheme",x="Month")+
scale_x_datetime(limits=c(inf,sup),breaks = date_breaks("1 month"),labels=date_format("%b"))+
facet_grid(Sex~.,scales="free",drop=TRUE)+guides(size=FALSE)
direplot
```

[image]

Anyway, the plot is informative but still not perfect:

- boxes or bars would be better than points. I had tried boxplot() with no good results as coord_flip and facet don't work well with this function.
- I would like the bars/boxes to "stop" when the value "yes" in the dropped column is encountered and then resume with the next available relocation (don't know if it is feasible).
- move the labels of the categories "male" and "female" on the opposite side of the y axes, under the y-axis label.

Any implementations to the code or advices would be much appreciated and if you need clarifications, I'm at disposition.
Thank you very much in advance,

Vagabond

Here my data:

```
   dires<-        "Name     Date    Sex Year Dropped
    1    Nymeria 20110603 Female 2011      no
    2    Nymeria 20110604 Female 2011      no
    3    Nymeria 20110605 Female 2011      no
    4    Nymeria 20110606 Female 2011      no
    5    Nymeria 20110607 Female 2011      no
    6    Nymeria 20110609 Female 2011      no
    7    Nymeria 20110610 Female 2011     yes
    8    Nymeria 20110811 Female 2011      no
    9    Nymeria 20110812 Female 2011      no
    10   Nymeria 20110816 Female 2011      no
    11   Nymeria 20110817 Female 2011      no
    12   Nymeria 20110818 Female 2011      no
    13   Nymeria 20110825 Female 2011     yes
    14     Ghost 20110518   Male 2011      no
    15     Ghost 20110520   Male 2011      no
    16     Ghost 20110521   Male 2011     yes
    17     Ghost 20110609   Male 2011      no
    18     Ghost 20110610   Male 2011      no
    19     Ghost 20110612   Male 2011      no
    20     Ghost 20110619   Male 2011      no
    21     Ghost 20110620   Male 2011      no
    22     Ghost 20110621   Male 2011      no
    23     Ghost 20110622   Male 2011      no
    24     Ghost 20110704   Male 2011      no
    25     Ghost 20110721   Male 2011      no
    26     Ghost 20110725   Male 2011     yes
    27 Grey_wind 20110515   Male 2012      no
    28 Grey_wind 20110516   Male 2012      no
    29 Grey_wind 20110524   Male 2012      no
    30 Grey_wind 20110610   Male 2012      no
    31 Grey_wind 20110611   Male 2012      no
    32 Grey_wind 20110614   Male 2012      no
    33 Grey_wind 20110615   Male 2012      no
    34 Grey_wind 20110630   Male 2012     yes
    35 Grey_wind 20110721   Male 2012      no
    36 Grey_wind 20110725   Male 2012      no
    37 Grey_wind 20110726   Male 2012      no
    38 Grey_wind 20110727   Male 2012      no
    39 Grey_wind 20110731   Male 2012     yes
    40      Lady 20110515 Female 2012      no
    41      Lady 20110516 Female 2012      no
    42      Lady 20110530 Female 2012      no
    43      Lady 20110610 Female 2012      no
    44      Lady 20110613 Female 2012      no
    45      Lady 20110614 Female 2012      no
    46      Lady 20110615 Female 2012     yes
    47      Lady 20110727 Female 2012      no
    48      Lady 20110731 Female 2012      no
    49      Lady 20110802 Female 2012      no
    50      Lady 20110808 Female 2012      no
    51      Lady 20110809 Female 2012      no
    52      Lady 20110811 Female 2012     yes"
    traj <- read.table(text=dires, header = TRUE)
```

**EDIT** I add a gimp-edited picture of what would be an ideal result. Probably it is not possible to directly obtain such a plot in R, but the closer, the merrier.
[image]

**EDIT2** after some experimenting, I was able to attain something much closer, albeit still not perfect, to what I had originally in mind. Since my supervisor told me that she didn't need the single dates for this graph, but just the periods, I restructured the data in order to generate the time spans between one transmitter "drop" and the other. Then I just increased the size of the single points in order to obtain something that looks like a bar. If it is of interest to the community I can post the code (the code snippet does not seem to work)

Comment: @agstudy - I just rolled it back.

Comment: Why the Year column is different from the year part of your Date column?

Comment: @agstudy Hi! because otherwise the data would have been displayed in two years (at least that's what happened) , and I need to make a comparison between animals (even though they were radiotracked in 2 different seasons). Maybe there was a more elegant way, but uniforming the dates worked well enough :-)

Comment: @Vagabond_20 but how do you get the second plot?

Comment: @agstudy the one I just posted is a gimp-edited version of the first one (doesn't look very "professional"), and it represents what I'd like to obtain in R (and I don't know if it's actually feasible).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
traj$Tracked = ifelse(traj$Dropped=='yes',0,1)
ggplot(traj, aes(x=Date, y=Tracked, fill=Sex ))+geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')+facet_grid(Name~.)+scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,1))
```

[image]

Comment: @mso Hi! thank you for your contribution! the ifelse() +geom_bar() idea is worth exploring. Unfortunately it seems that the Year factor has to be dropped in the process.

Comment: Year should be part of Date. If you want seasonal change put date_month value in one column, or maybe just month.